# firebase firestore function working intermittently

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

here is my code:

```
const q = query(
  collection(dataBase, "recordings"),
  orderBy("createdAt"),
  limitToLast(1)
);
await getDocs(q).then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((element) => {
    let data = element.data();

    if (data.reviewedByUser.includes(userId)) {
      setUpdated(updated + 1);
    } else {
      setInfo((arr) => [...arr, data]);
    }
  });
});
```

why it is working intermittently:
some of the recordings that I didnt reviewed dont show. Alas, the database dosent fetch them.
Thanks in advance for the answers!

this Async function is executed in a useEffect hook. Accidently, the main useEffect function was Asynchronous. I wrapped it in a regular function. will it help?

Comment: Is `query` an asynchronous function?

Comment: @Ram only getDocs in this example is async. firebase `query` function merely *describes* the query you want to perform, it doesn't execute it